# Switch two enums with one switch

Tags: ios, swift, enums

Suppose I have 2 enum, one is a list of animals and another its possible sizes.

Let's say I want to get its sound with a function, based on the animal and its size.

Is it possible, in some way, to make a two-enum switch simultaneously?

```
enum Animal {
  case dog
  case cat
  case bird
}

enum Size {
  case small
  case big
}

func soundForAnimal(_ animal: Animal, size: Size) {

    switch animal, size {
        case .dog, .small:
          print ("wuuf")

        case .dog, .big:
          print("wooof")

        case .cat, .small:
          print("Miau")

        case .cat, .big:
          print("MIAAAAUU")

        case .bird, .small:
          print ("piu")

        case .bird, .big:
          print("pioo")
    }
}
```

The code above is an example of what I would like to achieve, but i can't figure how.

Comment: You almost got it. Write instead `switch (animal, size)`, and `case (.dog, .small):`. You were just missing parenthesis to do a switch on a tuple.

Comment: Thanks, your comment was very helpful!

Comment: The Swift syntax, and many others, are documented in the Swift language guide. Strongly recommended read. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID127

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close. Make the switch create a tuple:

```
enum Animal {
  case dog
  case cat
  case bird
}

enum Size {
  case small
  case big
}

func soundForAnimal(_ animal: Animal, size: Size) {

    switch (animal, size) {
        case (.dog, .small):
          print ("wuuf")

        case (.dog, .big):
          print("wooof")

        case (.cat, .small):
          print("Miau")

        //and so on...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
Your answer and Larme's comment were very helpful!